# MongoDB on mLab authentication fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Created a new mLab account and created a database as per the steps here http://docs.mlab.com/#create-sub . Trying to connect to the database using mongo shell and mongoose Node.js module but I see the 'Authentication Failed' errorin both cases.

In Mongo shell the command is, I have double checked the credentials

```
mongo ds012345.mlab.com:56789/dbname -u dbuser -p dbpassword
```

Error:

```
MongoError: authentication fail
at Function.MongoError.create (E:\Gatsby\notmongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
```

Using Mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;

var uri = '<correct mongo uri here>';

var connection = mongoose.createConnection(uri,
{    
User: '<uname>',
Password: '<pwd>'
});
connection.on('open', function() {

console.log('connection established!!!');

new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {
    console.log('listDatabases succeeded');
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result); 
});
```

});

Error:: MongoConnect Error MongoError:authentication fail

Is there anything else that needs to be done on the mLab console or anything else that I might be doing wrong or missing?

Comment: did you create a new user for your database? or `dbuser` and `dbpassword` are your mLab account credentials?

Comment: that's right, had to add a new user for the database it connected with it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You needs to create a new user for the database in mLab account.and login with that created user on mlab account.then click on specific database and click on users tab, see in image below:
[image: users tab and add new user]

Now fill the form and create user for database. See in image below :

[image]

Now, in the code use the following string for connection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoDB = "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds241489.mlab.com:41489/<DB Name>";

mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
    useMongoClient: true
});

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

Answer (score 9):

I run into this same issue and in my case it was a problem of client version compatibility, as explained [here](http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#version-compatibility).

My mLab mongo database was version 3.4.9 but the client command-line version that I had, which came from the official Ubunty Xenial repos, was version 2.6.10.

This errored out with "authentication failed" even though the credentials being used (database credentials, not mlab user credentials) were correct.

Comment: This turned out to be exactly the issue in my case. I had 2.6.something, probably as a result of a simple apt-get in Linux Mint. I therefore obtained 3.6.2 using the documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ and voila, authentication suddenly succeeds. Thank you greatly.

Comment: This was my issue as well.

Comment: @Ashish mongo --version

Comment: @JulianCerruti mongodb version 3.6

Answer (score 7):

You are probably using you mLab credentials for `dbuser` and `dbpassword`.

You should **create a new user for the database** in using mLab's web interface and try to login with that user.

Here is how you can create a user for a database in mLab:

1. Select Databse
2. Switch to *Users* tab
3. Click `add database user`

Answer (score 6):

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 var mongoDB = "mongodb://user:123456@ds114989.mlab.com:13936/brary";

 mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
    useMongoClient: true
 });

 var db = mongoose.connection;

 db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

Note:
You need to create a user for your database on Mlab. This is not your account login details on Mlab.
Here my  is replaced with **user** and **dbpassword** replaced with **123456**
If your password contains a special character like @, # u need to escape it by enclosing 'dbuser':'dbpassword'

Comment: I think this is missed by most new users to Mlab or databases in general. Your Mlab user(s) is NOT the same as your db instance user, and a separate one must be created for each db you create.

Comment: Thank you to invest your time on this answer. I wasted 1 complete day to resolve that issue and finally found your answer to solve this issue. Thank you man <3.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting from Robomongo / Robo 3T? make sure the auth mechanism is **SCRAM-SHA-1**

[image: Auth Mechanism]

Answer (score 0):

are your sure you use your database user name and password?
because in most cases people use their account user name.

select your db and click on users then you can find your db user name