# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mlab

i'm trying to connect my google cloud app engine to mlab and it will insert data into in it. In my code i am using moongoose. when i try to insert my values it gives me error that

```
 (node:16) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
at /app/db/register.js:66:12
at $initialConnection.then.err (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:556:14)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

here my register.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var LoginInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema
  ({
    email : String,
    user: String,
    password: String,
    passwordConfirm : String,
    passwordRetrieval : String
  });

var User = mongoose.model('User',LoginInfoSchema);


router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
      var validatorUser = {
            email : req.body.email ,
            user : req.body.user ,
            password : req.body.password,
            passwordConfirm : req.body.passwordConfirm,
            passwordRetrieval : req.body.passwordRetrieval

      };
      var putUser = {
        email : req.body.email ,
        user : req.body.user ,
        password : req.body.password,
        passwordRetrieval : req.body.passwordRetrieval
      };
      req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
      req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
      req.checkBody('user', 'username is required').notEmpty();
      req.checkBody('password' , 'password is not empty').notEmpty();
      req.checkBody('passwordConfirm' , 'paswword should be same').equals
      (req.body.password);
      req.checkBody('passwordRetrieval' , 'password retrieval key is not     empty').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    res.redirect('/webrtc.js');
  }
  else{
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(putUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
    putUser.password = hash;
    });//end of hashing.
    });//end of generating salt.

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(putUser.passwordRetrieval, salt, function(err, hash) {
    putUser.passwordRetrieval = hash;
    });//end of hashing.
    });//end of generating salt.

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds243212.mlab.com:43212/userinfo"
     ,{useNewUrlParser : true} ,function(err , db){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    db.collection("users").findOne({ email: {
            "$regex": "^" + req.body.email + "\\b", "$options": "i"
        }},function(er , mail){
      if(mail)
      {
        console.log(mail);
        res.redirect('/');
        console.log('email already taken');
      }
      else
      {

      db.collection("users").insertOne(putUser, function(error, result) {
          if(error) console.log(error);
          //console.log(result);
          console.log("1 document inserted");
        });
        res.redirect('/');
        }// end of else part of check emai already taken
        });
      });//end of mongoose connection callback function
    }//end of validation success.
});//end of post method register callback function


module.exports = router;
```

this code work fine with local mongodatabase but when i deploy it on google cloud server it always comes with error.
please help.

Comment: What is output of the `if(err) console.log(err);`  before `db.collection("users")` ,  You were unable to connect and you did't handle it

Comment: @ArifKhan acutally it is on google cloud server , so how do i know what is output of console error.

Comment: @ArifKhan when i locally tried to connect to mlab it say authentication failed and error about collection that is above.

Comment: You can see `App Engine services` log inside `Logging` console

Comment: Probably you are passing wrong username and password  in `mongoose.connect()` or invalid url

Comment: @ArifKhan i use password and username which they ask me at adduser in mlab. and link is correct.

Comment: You should like to refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49789823/3461055

Comment: @ArifKhan hey now it gives me Mongodb authentication error and also callback is not function.

Comment: do i need some port opening thing in google app engine?